# What is marble hornets mode and what does it do?

Tags: slender-the-eight-pages

In Slender what does marble hornets mode do? I have been trying to find out.

Answer (score 2):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slender:_The_Eight_Pages#Development_and_release):

> From version 0.9.5 on successfully completing the game for the first
>   time in an earlier version unlocks "MH Mode". This mode starts off and
>   ends like an "Entry" from the web series Marble Hornets, which is
>   based on the Slenderman mythos. This mode also suggests that the round
>   of gameplay is actually a recorded video. There is static on the top
>   and bottom of the screen, and the different types of music that play
>   as the player collects more and more pages play. If the player beats
>   the game for the first time in this version (without having beaten it
>   in an earlier version first) they not only unlock "MH Mode", but
>   unlock "Daytime Mode" aswell. Beating both of these modes will then
>   unlock "$20 Mode". These modes are now listed in the "Extras" portion
>   of the menu screen

Comment: Marble hornets was a youtube series about an amateur film maker's  paranoia and obsession with an entity he described as "the slender man" the tale is told through a third party attempting to piece together the fate of his friend after his disappearance. I would strongly suggest giving it a look,  if you have an interest in the slender man mythos,  as not only is it closely connected,  but was in fact the origin of slender man as we know him.